# C# Styles without using xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles

I'm trying to make an application that has specifically styled buttons. To do this i have been using Expression Web 4 and C# to do my application.

The thing is that i am making the buttons in my program dynamically, so therefore i can't really 'hard-code' the buttons in the XAML file. I have the style i want as an XAML though. I was wondering how i can add a style to a button using the C# file instead.

Or, if that is not possible, perhaps there is some way that i can restructure the program to allow dynamically created buttons to be created.

Comment: Let me know if you need any sort of clarification :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

does the following code works ? :

```
myDynamicallyGeneratedButton.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["ButtonStyle"]);
```

`ButtonStyle` is the key of the style in an application level style resource

Comment: Thanks, worked a charm. That's exactly what i was looking for... couldn't seem to find it anywhere in the documentation. Thanks :)

Comment: How about global styles that have no string key?